ASP.NET MVC resets int to 0 on each post
I have, what I feel at least is a very simple forgot password page.  My idea here is to keep an int and count the int up and if a threshold is reached the model fails. What I can't figure out is why my int goes back to 0 on each post.
Here is my controller method:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgetPassword(Models.Portal.ForgetPasswordModel forgetPasswordModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        forgetPasswordModel.isEmail = Helper.Validation.IsValiEmailAddress(forgetPasswordModel.AccountName);
        forgetPasswordModel.ForgetAttempt = forgetPasswordModel.ForgetAttempt + 1;

        if (forgetPasswordModel.ForgetPasswordReset == Models.Portal.ForgetPasswordReset.Success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "Portal", new Models.Portal.ResetPasswordModel());
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ShowForgetPasswordError = true;
        }
    }

    return View(forgetPasswordModel);
}

Here is my view
@model AuthFrameworkMVCSite.Models.Portal.ForgetPasswordModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAuthFramework.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgetPassword", "Portal", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h2>Username/Email Address</h2>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName)
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
    if (ViewBag.ShowForgetPasswordError == true)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
            Something went wrong.  Please try again.
        </div>
    }
}
<div id="loader" style="display:none">
    Loading...
</div>

This is my model:
public class ForgetPasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public bool isEmail { get; set; }
    public ForgetPasswordReset ForgetPasswordReset { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ForgetAttempt { get; set; }
}

public enum ForgetPasswordReset
{
    Failure,
    Success
}

Any help is appreciated. I am passing back the model after incrementing the value.

Add a @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ForgotAttempt) to the page.
When using MVC an important factor is that the "Model" gets sent to the view engine to compose the HTML that goes to the browser. It does not go to the browser. When you format a call from the browser back to the controller with a Form POST. What gets sent back is what gets parsed from input controls in the page. What gets sent back is basic name-value data in the request body which MVC will populate into whatever class declaration, or arguments it finds in the requested method. If the POST data does not contain values for each property in the object or parameter, those values are left as defaults.
